# Increase the default disc space for Docker Images on macOS

Tags: docker

on macOS Sierra (10.12.2) I have Docker v1.13.0 installed.

For all created images, the disc space for / is allocated to 63Gb as on the following screenshot

[image]

**Question:** How I can increase the space available let's say from 63Gb to 150Gb?

Docker Info

```
Containers: 1
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 3
Server Version: 1.13.0
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 03e5862ec0d8d3b3f750e19fca3ee367e13c090e
runc version: 2f7393a47307a16f8cee44a37b262e8b81021e3e
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.9.4-moby
Operating System: Alpine Linux v3.5
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 15.65 GiB
Name: moby
ID: PUCA:LCD6:6LUP:IQ37:AZAX:GVW7:HVY5:MVOW:7WSJ:QUKO:QKCK:Q5EN
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 25
 Goroutines: 42
 System Time: 2017-01-28T14:50:13.838004112Z
 EventsListeners: 2
No Proxy: *.local, 169.254/16
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
```

The output of *~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/* is

```
total 304
drwxr-xr-x  12 cvb  staff   408B Jan 28 13:00 .
drwxr-xr-x  22 cvb  staff   748B Jan 28 13:00 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 cvb  staff    64K Jan 28 13:00 console-ring
-rw-r--r--   1 cvb  staff    64K Jan 28 12:59 console-ring.0
-rw-r--r--   1 cvb  staff     5B Jan 28 13:00 hypervisor.pid
-rw-r--r--   1 cvb  staff     0B Jan 28 12:59 lock
drwxr-xr-x   2 cvb  staff    68B Jan 28 12:59 log
-rw-r--r--   1 cvb  staff    17B Jan 28 13:00 mac.0
-rw-r--r--   1 cvb  staff    36B Jan 28 12:59 nic1.uuid
-rw-r--r--   1 cvb  staff     5B Jan 28 13:00 pid
-rw-r--r--   1 cvb  staff    94B Jan 28 13:00 syslog
lrwxr-xr-x   1 cvb  staff    12B Jan 28 13:00 tty -> /dev/ttys000
```

Comment: What is the output of `ls -lah ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux` ?

Comment: @Salem, I updated the question with the directory listing

Comment: Is there no way to update the default size of containers in storage configuration file?
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd#storage-opt dm.basesize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even in 1.13.0 it is a difficult process and probably all your containers and images will be wiped. Follow the steps  here:

https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/371#issuecomment-262826610

Regards

Answer (score 1):

These containers are running inside of the VM, so you have to increase the disk size allocated to that VM in order to get more space for your containers.

How did you create your docker host?  Did you use docker-machine or boot2docker?

Also,  it's not a good practice to allocate a lot of space to the containers,  what you can do is to create an external volume and mount it inside of your container.

Comment: I did not use  docker-machine or boot2docker, just installed Docker and that's it, i need to check what this guy has created during the installation. You are right, it does not sound good to allocate so much space. I was making a 'quick-and-dirty' PoC and came up with the quested asked. I mounted a directory eventually, yet the question is still open.

Comment: According to this https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/  docker for mac comes bundled with virtual box.

Comment: Vlad that's incorrect. The link says clearly it uses hyperkit which takes the place of virtualbox.